# Reading "alternative" keys with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Shortly:

How can I read different keys like ESC, ENTER, CTRL, ALT using Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `KeyStroke` identifies actions on the keyboard, it will allow you to act on different key events.

What you need to do is map actions to each key, like so:

```
// Create key stoke and bind the key stroke to an action
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("alt"), "actionName");

// Add the action to the component
component.getActionMap().put("actionName",
    new AbstractAction("actionName") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
);
```

The action will be invoked once the key stroke is pressed.

Also it may be helpful to read about `KeyStroke` at:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html

I hope this helps and that I understood what you meant by 'read different keys'

Comment: Both good answers, but you got more to the point. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to help you capturing the keyboard's pressed key ([Oracle website](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)):

```
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {
    ...//where initialization occurs:
    typingArea = new JTextField(20);
    typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

        //Uncomment this if you wish to turn off focus
        //traversal.  The focus subsystem consumes
        //focus traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.
        //If you uncomment the following line of code, this
        //disables focus traversal and the Tab events 
        //become available to the key event listener.
        //typingArea.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    ...
    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
    }

    /** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
    }

    /** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
    }
    ...
    private void displayInfo(KeyEvent e, String keyStatus){

        //You should only rely on the key char if the event
        //is a key typed event.
        int id = e.getID();
        String keyString;
        if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            keyString = "key character = '" + c + "'";
        } else {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            keyString = "key code = " + keyCode
                    + " ("
                    + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode)
                    + ")";
        }


        ...//Display information about the KeyEvent...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the Sun tutorial on [key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).